# URL в iOS  через XIB

Tags: url, objective-c, ios

Добрый день уважаймые гуру. Есть вопрос с которым не могу дать ладу. Облазивши куча сайтов просто не нашел нужного мне =( По этому не критикуйте сильно.

У меня есть

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wot-news.com/ajax/load_stat?mdata=%@"];
```

После **"mdata"** мне нужно вбить вместо **"%@"** значения коротое вводит пользователь в поле **Text Field** расположеный в XIB и при клике на **Button** происходит загрузка данного URL. Потом оно парситься, но это уже не важно...

Помогите это реализовать, кто может напишите код, кто знает что-то подобное поделитесь ссылкой.

----------------------------Продолжу тенденцию писать рабочий код, после успешного теста

Все просто, я сделал IBAction привязал его к кнопке.

```
-(IBAction)getInfo:(id)sender
{
    NSString  *urlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://wot-news.com/ajax/load_stat?mdata=%@", self.nick.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlText];

    //Конечно не забываем убирать клавиатуру, а то она за 15 тестов меня задолбала. 
    [self.nick resignFirstResponder];
```

Балуйтесь! Всем спасибо за помошь! 
P.S. не забудте подвязать кнопку!

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вы составляете URL, не заменив кусок строки? Сначала замените в строке %@ на то, что надо, затем делайте из полученной строки URL. Потому что иначе вам снова понадобиться вытаскивать строку из URL, заменять кусок, и паковать в новый URL.

Comment: Я представлял это неким другим обрахом. Как в любом браузере скрыто http:// когда вы вводите название сайта браузер сам добавляет http:// тоже самое и хочу сделать я =) Я думал так убдет проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
NSString *urlTemplate = @"http://wot-news.com/ajax/load_stat?mdata=%@";
NSString *expandedUrlTemplate = 
          [NSString stringWithFormat:urlTemplate, __here_your_string__];
NSUrl *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:expandedUrlTemplate];
```

Comment: Только лучше все же `NSString *expandedUrlTemplate =
[NSString stringWithFormat:urlTemplate ,__here_your_string__];`

Comment: Не получилось =( Много error,  когда убрал crash

Comment: @aknew: точно, спасибо! Исправлю ответ.

Comment: @Святослав: а где ошибки, где креш? Тут или ещё где-то?

Comment: Crash был на URL

Comment: в вопросе написал как мне подсказали сделать, и оно получилось !